# Regular Expression take a part of a string PHP

Tags: php, regex

For example I have the following string

```
$s = "asd$5asd";
```

how can I take only the part that contains the "$5" that comes after a "d"
in php we have the following

```
preg_mach //returns int number of matches
preg_replace //returns the string with a replaced content
//---------------------
preg_grep    //it greps but how to grep the "$5" 
             //that comes after "d" without grepping the "d" it's self ???
```

my regex is

```
/((coupon|enter)\x20code\x20)("([^"]+)")/
```

i want to grep the value of the forth brackets ($4)

Comment: Use [`preg_match_all('#d\$([0-9])#', $s, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)`](http://us.php.net/preg_match) to get all the matches. `$matches[1]` will contain all instances of the string you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends exactly what you are looking to match but the following will return all matches -

```
preg_match_all('/d(\$[0-9]+)/i',$s,$aMatches);
```

`$aMatches[1]` contains an array of all matches. Example matches - $5 $10 $20 (Only matches $ and a number of any length)

Comment: It is worth noting this is an elaboration on @DCoders answer. I noticed his regex does not support multiple numbers so for example, it would not match $10

Comment: ok, if my regex was '/((coupon|enter)\x20code\x20)("([^"]+)")/
' how can i grep the fourth bracket ($4)...thanks

Comment: @user1225246 have you got an example string that you would send and what would you expect to return?

Comment: my string is _________$25 off $50+ order at Gardens Alive! Use coupon code 0152513 at checkout______ the result is 0152513

Comment: @user1225246 are you trying to get the value of the coupon code? So the actual code itself from the string?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14238/discussion-between-chris-and-user1225246)